# How to reinstall or just make Application Request routing module show in IIS Manager console

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to reinstall IIS, and I noticed application requset routing module is not shown in IIS manager. I decided to install in using Web platform installer but inside there it says I have module installed which is true when I go to `C:\Program Files\IIS` I can see folder "Application Request Routing" there but why IIS can't see it now. Using web platform installer is not possible to uninstall or reinstall module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not easy but important files are: administration.config and applicationHost.config file inside `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`
folder. Inside `administration.config` file, inside `moduleProviders` section I had to add :

```
   <add name="WebFarmFramework" type="Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarm.WebFarmModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarm, Version=7.1.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   <add name="ApplicationRequestRouting" type="Microsoft.Web.Management.Arr.ArrModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.Arr, Version=7.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

That made Application request module show in IIS manager. After I opened it showed errors but errors are easy to understand. I needed to make same changes inside `application.config` file, inside `configSection` section:

```
 <section name="diskCache" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
 <section name="proxy" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
```

These are changes I made to those files recently but there are probably few other sections I had to add inside `application.config` file, but idea was to copy those sections from some other computer which has good configuration.

Comment: You should not manually edit those files. Go to Control Panel's Programs you can easily uninstall the module and then install it again.

Comment: You can uninstall application request routung module from control panel?

Comment: why didn't you take a look?

Comment: I did ofcourse. I asked you because it seemed your are so confident that there is ability to delete this module throught control panel. Anyway problem is solved and there is answer so someone can solve similar problem when some module( lot of others are) is not possible (or not easy to find) in UI.

Comment: but I can uninstall, so not sure what exactly happened in your machine. It is an MSI installer, so unless MSI engine is corrupt, you should be able to uninstall it from there.

Comment: It was installed using Web platform installer, and I tried to uninstall it there first.